# How to visualize the angular frequency in SHM?

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, visualization

Can anyone define how can i visualize the angular frequency(ω) in a SHM y(t)=R sin(ωt+ϕ) (where ω=2π/T).Bcoz we can visualize frequency(f=1/T) as **number of times the process is repeated in 1 sec** so how to define this angular frequency ω.

Also in SHM (a =–kx/m) then here why do we define ***k/m = ω^2***

so plz tell me how to visualize the angular frequency in SHM

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411637/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

You can relate it to $\omega$ in uniform circular motion(the angular velocity) as SHM can be visualised as projection of uniform circular motion.

Comment: The constructions sometimes goes by the name "reference circle" which might help in searching for it.