# How to derive $i=I_0 \sin(wt)$ in alternating current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, differentiation

Our teacher taught us today that instantaneous value of current in Alternating Current is
$$i=I_0 \sin(wt)$$

Where $I_0$ is the amplitude and $wt$ is the angular speed times time. Now, she didn't really explain the mathematics behind this, because we just have to apply it like this. Now I was wondering to know, how come that amplitude times the sine function equals me the value of instantaneous value of current. How was this equation derived?

I believe it might be some sort of integral involved, but I can't see what to differentiate integrate. I know that the second derivative of speed would be $w$ (omega) here and times $time(t)$ would actually give me the sine function. Therefore I see it somewhat meaningful if the equation was just :
$$i = \sin(wt)$$
even though it doesn't make any use of Amps. Any piece of wiki or documentation you might have around this would gladly help.

Comment: [Why are AC quantities represented by sine waves always?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54290/37364)

Comment: Just a note, you can write the Greek letter omega by typing: \omega

Comment: It's essentially the definition of "alternating current", so it cannot be derived.

Comment: This is imposed by the source, mathematically is an axiom.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I was wondering to know, how come that amplitude times the sine function equals me the value of instantaneous value of current. How was this equation derived?

It isn't derived, and it can't be proved mathematically.

It's a definition or a premise of some given problem your instructor was discussing.

We are interested in how systems respond to sinusoidal excitations, because for linear systems we can use Fourier analysis to generalize how the system would respond to any stimulus if we know its response to sinusoidal stimulus at different frequencies. We can also prove that if the stimulus of a *linear, time-invariant* (LTI) system is sinusoidal, then the response of the circuit (its node voltages and branch currents) will also be sinusoidal with the same frequency.

But in any given problem, it's just a given of the problem that the stimulus is sinusoidal, not a mathematically provable property of the system.

> Therefore I see it somewhat meaningful if the equation was just :
> $$i = sin(wt)$$
> even though it doesn't make any use of Amps.

Well, current has units of amps, so if you have an equation for current that doesn't give units of amps you have a problem.

The easy way to resolve it in this case is to multiply the sinusoid by a pre-factor that

1. Contains the units (amps)
2. Gives the magnitude of the signal. That is, it tells you whether this signal has a peak value of 1 A, 10 A, 10<sup>-6</sup> A, or some other value.

That is the function of the $I_0$ factor in the definition given by your instructor.

Comment: Very clear explanation. So being sinusoidal is its property, more of an axiom and same goes for its formula if I understood this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize that AC signals do not, in general, have to be represented by sine waves in fact they do not even have to be periodic, i.e. expressible as Fourier series. An alternating current is just any kind of current that does not have a constant direction. For such currents, the polarity must shift, e.g. for some voltage as a function of time $V(t)$, $V(t)<0$ for some values of $t$ and $V(t)>0$ for some other values of $t$. The sine wave currents are often employed because they closely model the kinds of current found in many electrical technologies, however, even in this case, sine waves are not the only signals found.

Comment: Your equation for I(t) is not universal. It only applies if you're talking about the current-voltage relationship of a capacitor. Other components have different relationships between I(t) and V(t).

Comment: The voltage signals in computers may be square waves, but they are (in nearly all modern technologies) not AC according to your definition. The associated currents are typically not square waves (although they might be derived from square waves with appropriate filters).

Comment: @Albertus Your definition $I = \frac{dV}{dt}$ is wrong, since the definition of current is $I = \frac{dQ}{dt}$... You can see it is wrong since you have a units problem. Your current, according to your definition, has units of voltage divided by time, but it should have units of charge divided by time.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I am not sure where my head was at on that one! I have fixed the errors, so @FabDust take another look.

Answer (score -1):

Basically if you look at the graph of any alternating current:

[image]

you can see the graph, I'm assuming you understand the physics behind alternating current. If you do it's pretty obvious that the graph of the current $i$ is just a sine wave where the amplitude is the magnitude of the current being passed and the frequency is what it is in every sinusoid, how fast the current is basically, so by intuition we have $i = I_0 \sin (\omega t)$ , also $I_0$ is what gives the current its units. Feel free to ask any questions because I'm not sure I understood ur initial question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).